# Istantiate Class Coffeescript in different folders

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm studying coffee from official docs and i can't figure out how can i use classes and objects in a usual folder structure.

Let's take this scenario :

```
-- scripts
   -- coffee
      -- HeaderCtrl.js.coffee
      -- AnimationCtrl.js.coffe
   main.coffee
```

now let's assume that in main.coffee i would like, when document ready, to instantiate my Header and Animation Controller, how can i do it?

p.s i know how to instantiate an object (`header = new HeaderCtrl()`) but i don't know how to use lie namespaces in js to call things in different locations.

Many thanks guys

Comment: Are you using CoffeeScript on the client side (browser) or on the server side (node.js)?

Comment: What other research have you done? Have you tried looked at something like [require](http://requirejs.org/) requireJS for the client-side or [exports](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) on the server?

Comment: 1) client side.
2)  I tried to use requireJS but it seems to give lot of errors like mismatch and sintax error even if i have just a console log inside headerCtrl constructor so i decided to move 1 step at time

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need this i figured out to achieve what i would like to do using requireJS, doing something like this :

in `/script/controllers/HeaderCtrl.coffee`

```
define [], () ->
  class HeaderCtrl
    constructor: (@ref) ->
```

I declare a module with no dependencies

in `/scripts/main.coffee`

```
requirejs.config
  baseUrl: 'scripts'
  paths:
  HeaderCtrl: 'controllers/HeaderCtrl

require ['HeaderCtrl'], (HeaderCtrl) ->
  instance = new HeaderCtrl()
```

I pass it in requiresjsconfig and call it just after.

P.S Care when you include requirejs lib it must be the last file that you include in dom